# Squid3 Only Blocking iOS Facebook App

Tags: facebook, proxy, squid

I am using a proxy for logging purposes and blocking malicious sites.

I recently installed a squid3 proxy setup with SquidGuard. I have my iOS devices connected to it and all it working well except for 2 apps. The iOS Facebook and Twitter app will not update content, and eventually times out. I actually want the content to update. This only happens when coming out through the proxy. If I turn wifi off and connect 4G it works. All other internet apps on the iOS device work except Twitter and Facebook. Any thoughts? I am using a very simple proxy squid.conf file and SquidGuard is blocking a bunch of spyware/ad domains, but not facebook.com or twitter.com or akami.com/akamihd.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, the Facebook app for iOS does not support proxies at all. On my iPad, for instance, the app tries to connect directly to Facebook irrespective of proxy settings. One workaround is to redirect all of your device's traffic through a device that performs intercepting proxying